# Jumbled output in CMD.EXE with a manually allocated console

Tags: windows, user-interface, cmd, windows-console

I am getting frustrated.  I have a Windows GUI application that manually opens a console.  Calling `AllocConsole` and redirecting `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` all work flawlessly.  I can type any input and any output, and it works well.  The problem is that when I call `_wsystem` to run a CMD command, the output is garbage. The characters are jumbled. CMD isn't seamlessly integrated with the console.

I redirect output to the console as follows:

```
consoleHandleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
if (consoleHandleOut != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { 
    //freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); 
    freopen_s(&newStream, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout); 
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 
    SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, 
                 (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(newStream))); 
} else { 
    return FALSE; 
}
```

I do this for each handle.

Comment: We need more information. Are you using ANSI or Unicode strings? Post some code please.

Comment: Exactly what are you running in CMD? If it's not an internal command, you're blaming the wrong process.

Comment: I'm making a pseudoshell.  Anything you could type at the cmd prompt I want to do in my console after the user enters cmd and I spawn the cmd.exe

Comment: I'm using Unicode.  As a test, I call this  _wsystem(L"dir");  All the characters stay on one time.  It's like \r\n are discarded

Comment: I redirect output to the console like so

Comment: consoleHandleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  if (consoleHandleOut != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
   //freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
   freopen_s(&newStream, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
   setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
   SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(_fileno(newStream)));
  }
  else {
   return FALSE;
  }
Which I do for each handle

Comment: That did it!  Yeah, I used CONIN$, but thanks, but I have my "dingy moments".  But yeah, my code works flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

Change the open mode from "w" to "r+". For complete compatibility with the console API, console files should be opened with read-write access, which is how they're opened by default when a process allocates a console. For example, the C runtime detects a console handle for `isatty` by calling `GetConsoleMode`, which requires a handle with read access. This will fail if "CONOUT$" is opened with only write access.